# symfony 2 : Namespace "Acme" does not contain any mapped entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am following the book and on the page http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

While following the book I am trying to work on relationship of product and category table and  doctrine generate command is giving me following error.

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Acme
Generating entities for namespace "Acme"



  [RuntimeException]                                      
  Namespace "Acme" does not contain any mapped entities.  



doctrine:generate:entities [--path="..."] [--no-backup] name
```

Thx

Comment: ...and?  Can we see the code that's causing the error?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With

```
doctrine:generate:entity
```

you'll create new entity.

And when you add some attributes by hand with

```
doctrine:generate:entities AcmeDemoBundle:User
```

you'll create all accessor (getter and setter) of the entity User of AcmeDemoBundle

Comment: Hi Simone,
Thx for your reply.
Got it resolved. I had to move from .php to .yml. Will try with .php once I complete the book and get some exp with symfony2. 
Thx.

Comment: Btw, How can I close this question?

Answer (score 7):

This error will also come up if your projects (only?) Entity is namespaced incorrectly.  If you run the command

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle
```

and it produces the error

> [RuntimeException]
>   Bundle "MyBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.

Check the more specific command....

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle:MyEntity
```

And see if you get the error:

> [RuntimeException]
>   The autoloader expected class "MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity"
>   to be defined in file "/path/to/MyBundle/Entity/MyEntity.php".
>   The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or
>   namespace probably has a typo.

If so, well then, the error speaks for itself (hopefully) and the namespace/class name needs to be corrected.  Hopefully that is helpful to someone.

Comment: Replace `app/console` with `bin/console` if you are using Symfony 3+.

Answer (score 4):

The solution:

Update symfony files:

```
composer update
```

then create entities

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities BackendBundle
```

Answer (score 3):

Check that the PHP opening and (optional) closing tags

```
<?php
```

and

```
?>
```

are correct in your file.

They are *not* included when you copy paste from the tutorial at
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

I was stuck at the same problem. After looking at this post I started wondering why the syntax highlighting was broken and discovered that the opening and closing tags were missing. The error disappeared when the tags were included.

Comment: Please explain if you downvote. This is my first answer (Hi!) to return the favor. Visiting stackoverflow has helped me a lot with programming problems. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot about <?php i just copied from tutorial, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

In book http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html entity Porduct has been manually created. You wrote code to Product.php. All information about entity fields contains **in annotations**.
But entity Category has been created with

`php app/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity="AcmeStoreBundle:Category" --fields="name:string(255)"`

**Automatically generated entity** Caterory.php **doesn't contains annotations**. Symfony stored information in "Acme\StoreBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\Category.orm.yml".
That's why `php app/console doctrine:mapping:info` says that you have only 1 mapped entity - Category.

**Solving**
You may generate Product entity with `doctrine:generate:entity`
or
Manually add information about Product entity to "Acme\StoreBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\Category.orm.yml"
or
Delete "Acme\StoreBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\Category.orm.yml" and describe Category entity with annotations in Category.php

Answer (score 2):

I personally had the error because I was missing the folder/directory "Entity".

Comment: This catches me out every time

Answer (score 1):

One of the two things may be the problem,

1. make sure you have a use statement at the top, that is

   `use Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product;`

   It is not included in the example, they only displayed 
   `use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;`
2. When specifying target entity always specify full namespace if the entities are in different name spaces.
    example:

   `@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="category")`

   instead of:

   `@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")`

   The second one only works if the two entities are in same namespace and that entity has been called by `use` statement above the class.