# Steps in generating entity

Tags: symfony

I need help to generate entity, because when I tried the below one I get errors.

Create databse:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

Generate entity:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

Generate the `Getters` and `Setters`:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AiQABlogBundle/Entity/Profile
```

The above step gives this error:

> [RuntimeException]
>   Namespace "AiQABlogBundle\Entity\Profile" does not contain any mapped entities.

Answer (score 1):

In this post you find [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11465075/2935495)

Or You should enter this command

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AiQABlogBundle:Profile
```